# Create users with SSMS in Azure SQL PaaS

Tags: azure-sql-database

We're new to using SQL as a service. Since there's no gui for user management, we're having a hard time figuring out how to create users who are actually able to log in with SSMS. I can create users with access to the proper DBs, and use those users to access the DBs programatically, but not through SSMS. How do I create multiple users who can login and administrate SQL as a service databases?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to Azure SQL Database using the Admin user. You can automate creating many users using a script like below:

```
 declare @Name varchar(100),@sql varchar(400),@sql2 varchar(400),@sql3 varchar(400) ,@sql4 varchar(400) 
declare @psw varchar(10) = 'Traf@12345';
declare @T table (Name varchar(100)) ;
insert into @T values 
('SampleUser1'),
('SampleUser2')

While exists(select * from @T) 
begin 
   select top 1 @Name = name from @T 
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[sql_logins] WHERE [name] = @Name) 
   BEGIN 

      SET @sql = 'CREATE LOGIN '+'['+@name+']'+' WITH PASSWORD ='''+ @psw + '''; '
      EXEC (@sql) 
   END 
   DELETE FROM @T WHERE Name = @Name 
END
```

Below is the sequence that you need to create users:

---- ON SERVER LEVEL

```
CREATE LOGIN TestUser
    WITH PASSWORD = 'ThisIsAStrongPassword!' 
GO
```

---- create user on Master database Level

```
CREATE USER TestUser
    FOR LOGIN TestUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
```

---- create user on database level

```
CREATE USER TestUser
    FOR LOGIN TestUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
```

-- if you want the user to be able to create databases and logins

```
exec sp_addRoleMember 'dbmanager', 'TestUser';
exec sp_addRoleMember 'loginmanager', 'TestUser'
```

-- in each individual database, to grant dbo

```
exec sp_addRoleMember 'db_owner', 'TestUser';
```

Answer (score 0):

This document will be helpful for your requirement , 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/